# Pyarrow: How to specify partial schema

Tags: pyarrow

I am creating a table with some known columns and some dynamic columns. I would like to specify the data types for the known columns and infer the data types for the unknown columns. Is there a way to do this?

If I create a schema with only the known columns, then the other columns are ignored when creating the table:

```
n_legs = pa.array([2, 4, 5, 100])
animals = pa.array(["Flamingo", "Horse", "Brittle stars", "Centipede"])
pydict = {'n_legs': n_legs, 'animals': animals}
partialSchema = pa.schema([('n_legs', pa.int32())])
pa.Table.from_pydict(pydict, schema=partialSchema)

pyarrow.Table
n_legs: int32
----
n_legs: [[2,4,5,100]]
```

^^^ The `animals` column was omitted instead of inferred.

Comment: Is your real case coming from python data?  If so, can you specify the types when you create the arrays?  For example, `pa.array([2, 4, 5, 100], pa.int32())`?

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you! (You should write that as an answer for the "points")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to specify the data type for your inputs before you create the table, when you are creating your arrays.  Then you do not need to specify a schema:

```
n_legs = pa.array([2, 4, 5, 100], pa.int32())
animals = pa.array(["Flamingo", "Horse", "Brittle stars", "Centipede"])
pydict = {'n_legs': n_legs, 'animals': animals}
pa.Table.from_pydict(pydict)

pyarrow.Table
n_legs: int32
animals: string
----
n_legs: [[2,4,5,100]]
animals: [["Flamingo","Horse","Brittle stars","Centipede"]]
```